# Hive 3.1.1 install problem: Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path

Tags: hadoop, hive

Thanks to good information on tutorialspoint and stackoverflow, I'm nearly done installing Hive 3.1.1 with Hadoop 3.0.3 on Ubuntu on Oracle VirtualBox.

I try to run "bin/hive" from $HIVE_HOME and receive the following error:

```
"Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path."
```

I've edited bashrc to include:

```
    export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
    ....
    export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
    export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
    export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
    export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/*:.
    export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/lib/*:.
```

Hadoop connects correctly.

I've edited both hive-env.xml and hive-config.sh to include

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the file located at /hive/bin/hive.distro
The HADOOP_HOME and HADOOP_PREFIX variables must be set correctly inside this file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Hadoop connect correctly? There is a change from 3.x in default ports - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-9427 that may cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

set HADOOP_HOME in "hive-env.sh":

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop